# How to pick resistor values for a potentiometer?

Tags: voltage-divider, potentiometer

I have a potentiometer that ranges from 100-845 ohms and I have quite a hard time finding out resistor values for a range of 1V (100 ohm) and 5V (845 ohm). I am forced to use this potentiometer and cannot use one that goes to 0 ohm.

Edit: I need these voltage values to put them in an op amp to drive a NPN mosfet to make a current source of 4-20 mA. Like this:

[image]

Comment: For what you need the resistor values? What are you doing with the pot?

Comment: If it only has two active terminals, it's a rheostat, not a potentiometer.  Are you asking what external resistors you need to create a voltage divider that puts out between 1 and 5 volts varying with setting?  If so, what is your supply voltage?

Comment: NPN describes a BJT transistor; you said "NPN mosfet" but you probably mean "N-channel mosfet"

Comment: Yes thank you JYelton, do not pay attention to current source resistor values I know they are wrong

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: -Cristobol It's a potentiometer and yes that is my question. My supply is 12V but it isn't static. I could change it if needed.

Comment: Is this a fuel tank level sender or similar? I'm just triple checking: 1. The device has three terminals. 2. The resistance between the two ends of the track is 845 ohms. 3. The minimum resistance between the wiper and the bottom of the track is 100 ohms. 4. The resistance between the wiper and the top of the track at maximum is 0 ohms. Are all four points correct?

Comment: -Transistor Yes all of this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzXkF7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The equivelant circuit showing the tap-off points at max and min potentiometer settings and the resistance values.*

Now the problem becomes simple! The current through R2a is given by \$ I = \frac V R = \frac {4} {745} = 0.0054 \text A\$.

We need to drop 7 V across R1 so \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 7 {0.0054} = 1296 \ \Omega \$. 1.2 kΩ is the nearest E12 value and it may be good enough.

We want that 0.0054 A through R2b + R3 will give a 1 V drop. \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 1 {0.0054} = 185 \ \Omega\$. We can now find R3 = 185 - 100 = 85 Ω. 82 Ω is the nearest E12 value.

---

Results with E12 values:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAesqS.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Simulation results for standard E12 resistor values.

---

> I need these voltage values to put them in an op amp to drive a NPN mosfet to make a current source of 4 - 20 mA.

With your 150 Ω resistor in the feedback circuit your control will be as follows:

```
Pot   Voltage   Current
Min     1.0 V   1/150 =  6.6 mA  
Max     5.0 V   5/150 = 33.3 mA
```

For 4 - 20 mA you need \$ R = \frac V I = \frac 5 {0.02} = 250 \ \Omega \$.

```
Pot   Voltage   Current
Min     1.0 V   1/250 =  4 mA  
Max     5.0 V   5/250 = 20 mA
```

---

Don't forget to do your power dissipation calculations for the resistors. (P = I<sup>2</sup>R.)

Comment: The method is fine, but due to the late hour, you've made the mistake of calculating the current as 12V / 745Ω, when only 4V is being dropped across R2a.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it on my tablet before going to sleep. Now I don't have to think of a solution in my dreams.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing Transistor's drawing, we can simplify this to a bunch of series resistors
[image: 1]

R2a and R2b represent the pot, with it's total of 845Ω and min wipe of 100Ω. We need to find R1 and R3 such that there's 5V at the node between R1 and R2a, and 1V at the node between R2a and R2b.
We can find the current by dividing the voltage across R2a by its resistance 
\$ I = \frac{(5V - 1V)} {745Ω} = \frac {4V}{745Ω} = 5.369mA )\$

We can then use this to find out resistance values for R1 and 3. 
\$R1 = \frac{12V - 5V}{5.369mA} = \frac{7V}{5.369mA} = 1303.75 Ω\$
If we consider the resistance of R2b and R3 as one for now, then
\$ R1 + R2b = \frac{1V} {5.369mA} = 186.25 Ω.\$

Given R2b = 100Ω  \$R3 = 86.25Ω\$
These values are pretty awkward, and it becomes a tradeoff between how much you want to spend, what you can find, and how close to exactly 5V and 1V you need.

One option is to use trim pots, that allow you to get an arbirtary value. A 1k5Ω trim pot can (theoretically) be trimmed to 1303.75Ω, though it's also common to use a resistor in combination with a trim pot to make the job easier, such as a 1k2Ω resistor with a 150Ω trimmer.

You could also make this a bit easier by using a zener diode in place of R1 to drop the 7V. R2b is always going to drop 0.5369V, so getting a 0.463V zener or reference might a bit tricky.

82Ω is a readily available resistor value so this might suit if you can tolerate the error, or you can find 86.6Ω which is closer, or if you **really** need the accuracy you could use two, I've found 82Ω + 4.22Ω available at mouser which is pretty close.

You could also look at rescaling the current pump such that you need different voltages